# LaTeX Error: File `kpfonts.sty' not found

Tags: latex

I downloaded a template tried to run on my Texmaker. It says "LaTeX Error: File `kpfonts.sty' not found." How can I install this font on my system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu Packges](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-fonts-extra/filelist) this file is in a package called `texlive-fonts-extra`.
To  install this package use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you share me how you find the package name for this particular font..?

Comment: Sure, go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/. Under "Search the contents of packages" type the file name and choose "packages that contain files named like this" and search =)

Answer (score 4):

If a latex document which works in another latex installation fails to compile on your system, especially when asking for a certain file as in this case, pretty sure there is a whole *package* missing. In this case, it requires the latex package "kpfonts" which you have to install separately.
On Ubuntu, the best way to do this is an installation via apt-get.
Let's do a quick search:

```
apt-cache search kpfonts
```

points you to a package called texlive-fonts-extra.

```
apt-cache show texlive-fonts-extra
```

tells you that this package is a collection of different font packages, including kpfonts.

So the only thing you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

If you don't like installing all those other packages included in there, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/how-to-install-new-packages-on-texmaker-on-ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package `texlive-fonts-extra`.